# Need help for login sequence diagramm

Tags: uml, sequence, sequence-diagram

I’m newbie in Uml diagram.
I have 3 page:
Login,
Verify login, personal page. 
if login is valid , website redirect me in a personal page

else website redirect to login page again.

How I can draw a diagram sequence of login?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically draw an UML sequence diagram matching your requirements like this:
[image]

Please note that your question is not very detailed, so this diagram may not be correct regarding content, it just shows how to draw a sequence diagram.

**Edit**

For the case of unverifiably login data, you need a separate sequence because every sequence (in a UML diagram) is specified to have a single entry point as well as a single exit point. You could simply model it like this:

[image]

Comment: For the case of a failed login, see the edit in my answer. You will not need the Personal Page in that sequence because it will not be reached.

Comment: https://ibb.co/i8NNqy this is my diagram. In my university they introduced “alt” concept. The second “Line Life” rappresent the Verify Page. THE third line life rappresent a personal page. If login failure I should redirect lo the first line life ? Sorry so much.

Comment: You could model a sequence that consists of a failed login followed by a successful one, so combine the two from my answer. I haven't heard of alternative sequence paths (in my university) but there might be a possibility of modeling those. If it is a task from your teacher you better stick to his version in order to achieve a good grade ;-)

Comment: You're welcome! If you think my answer is the correct one, please mark it as correct. Grazie mile dalla Germania!
btw. I think it is valid to use some *alternative* sections in a UML sequence diagram, but it will make it more cluttered. Having a single diagram for each sequence is the easier (to understand) way to go.

Comment: You can use an `alt` fragment showing success and fail in one SD.